# How can one share information using the 'host-proof' paradigm?

Tags: javascript, security, cryptography, passwords

I am attempting to make a web-based secure password management and sharing utility, both as an academic exercise and to fully understand and feel safe about using it.

I really like the idea of a 'host-proof' application, where encryption/decryption is done on the client side using javascript and only encrypted information ever leaves the browser, much like PassPack or Clipperz. What I cannot figure out is how Passpack manages to allow people to share passwords. I cannot see how it can be done without either plain text or an encryption key being transferred to the other user via the server, making that process inherently break the "host-proof" paradigm.

Can anyone point me towards a solution to this?

Comment: If you can store the passwords in cleartext on the server, you can have each client send you the public part of their encryption keys, and transfer the password encrypted with that. I'm not sure you can do better without the sharer and recipient doing real key exchange.

Comment: Not really a programming question, but I'm not 100% sure if this is something for [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/), so I'll leave it be. Would suggest you try crypto and other forums too.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about crypto. Thanks for the suggestion, I will definitely post over there. I agree that maybe crypto isn't exactly right as this is really an architecture question, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three major obstacles you'd need to overcome to create such a system that is both useful and secure.

First, the user will have to enter his private key into the web interface.  RSA keys are typically at least 1024 bits long, so even if you use the relatively efficient base64 encoding (which is probably a bad choice as many of the characters used are visually similar) the user will have to enter 171 meaningless characters.  With a keyboard, this will be tedious and error-prone.

Second, the javascript code the client runs comes from the web server.  You are trying to avoid the risk of an attacker accessing plaintext passwords on the server by encrypting and decrypting in the client.  But if an attacker can access plaintext passwords stored on the server, they probably also have the ability to modify the javascript code that the server sends.  If the attacker can modify the javascript code, they can use the modified code to capture the user's secrets.

Finally, there is the security of the hardware and software running the client code.  If the  hardware and software the user uses is compromised (for instance with a keylogger) the secrets can be captured there.  So to be safe, the user will only be able to use computers he controls.  And if you can only use a computer you control, many of the advantages of a web-based system over a traditional client-server system are negated.

If you can tackle those problems, storing the public keys on the server as Inerdial seems like a good choice, although you'd then have the problem that the user has no way of knowing  if the public key sent by the server is really controlled by the person to whom they want to give their password and not by an attacker.

Nate Lawson mentions javascript cryptography in [his Google Tech Talk](http://youtu.be/ySQl0NhW1J0?t=9m45s).

Comment: I was willing to attempt to fix or live with those problems (on-screen keyboard, etc.). But I have been made aware of a few of Javascript's other shortcomings. What do you think about executing the client-side code in Adobe Flex/Air? I am not strong when it comes to Flex, but it seems to fit the bill of a compiled client-side code that can be verified upon transmission/download.

Comment: I don't see why it would be more verifiable than Javascript over HTTPS.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard: It's a single object that you can checksum, JavaScript can be *anywhere* on the site.

Comment: @HubertKario: and where is the user going to get the checksum code and correct checksum?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard: from the same place he can verify the digital signature on the Air code.